# How to select the first option using ngFor?

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-4, html-select, angular9

I'm trying to select the first option after the user enters the email, but keeps not selected.
Any solution?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxPu0.png)

HTML:

```
<label for="login"><b>Usuário:</b></label>
                <input type="email" id="login" name="login" ngModel class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail"
                    required autofocus (focusout)="onSelect()">

 <label><b>Empresa:</b></label>
                <select ngModel name="IdEmpresa" class="form-control" id="IdEmpresa" disabled="{{ disabled }}">
                    <option *ngFor="let empresa of empresas; index as i" value="{{empresa.id}}"
                    >{{ empresa.nome }}</option>
                </select>
```

TS:

```
onSelect() {
if ($("#login").val()== null || $("#login").val() =="") {

} else {
  this.erro = false;
  this.alertService.clear();

  let email = (document.getElementById("login") as HTMLInputElement).value;
  localStorage.setItem(constants.emailSafeguard, email);

  this.service.getEmpresas(email).subscribe(lista => {
    this.empresas = lista;

    if(lista.length > 1) {
      this.disabled = false;
    } else {
      this.disabled = true;
    }
  })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select has no value. Please change it like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedEmpresaId" name="IdEmpresa" class="form-control" id="IdEmpresa" [disabled]="disabled">
                    <option *ngFor="let empresa of empresas; index as i" [value]="empresa.id"
                    >{{ empresa.nome }}</option>
                </select>
```

And in ts (initial)

```
this.selectedEmpresaId = this.empresas[0].id;
```

---

Or with object instead of id

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedEmpresa" name="IdEmpresa" class="form-control" id="IdEmpresa" [disabled]="disabled">
                    <option *ngFor="let empresa of empresas; index as i" [value]="empresa"
                    >{{ empresa.nome }}</option>
                </select>
```

And in ts (initial)

```
this.selectedEmpresa = this.empresas[0];
```

Comment: It worked! thank you very much, I've been trying a few days